# ¿Cómo usar las funciones de sanitización y validación de la REST API de WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, validación, rest

La versión 2.0 beta 12 del plugin REST API de WordPress introduce las funciones [`rest_validate_request_arg`](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/blob/2.0-beta12/plugin.php#L275) y [`rest_sanitize_request_arg`](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/blob/2.0-beta12/plugin.php#L360) que según comentan en el anuncio, pueden servir para validar argumentos de consulta, además de parámetros de la solicitud.

Pero he buscado en la [documentación del plugin](http://v2.wp-api.org/) y en la [referencia del desarrollador de WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/) y no encuentro ejemplos del uso de estas funciones que prometen validación y sanitización de entradas. Antes de sumergirme en el código fuente, ¿alguien tiene ejemplos de cómo usarlas al registrar campos para nuestros recursos?

Comment: No tengo aún la respuesta, pero tal vez [el propio commit donde se introducen estas funciones](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/commit/c749796cea4dc697520989322dccb6292acbdb07) y se abandona la lógica previa, tenga la solución.